# Make Slider Images responsive Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have got a layout that looks the way i want on the webpage but the images aren't responsive. One column has a paragraph of text then in the other a slideshow.  If i use `class="img-circle"` it makes the image smaller than i would like. When i make the window smaller it cuts some of the image off. How can i make them responsive? I tried to use the carousel bootstrap has but i can't get them to align side by side.

```js
 $(".slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function () {
            $('.slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo('.slideshow');
        }, 4000);
```

```css
 .slideshow {
            margin: 45px auto;
            position: relative;
            width: 490px;
            height: 320px;
            padding: 10px;
            /*box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
        }

            .slideshow > div {
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                left: 10px;
                right: 10px;
                bottom: 10px;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




 <div class="container">
            <div class="d-inline h3">orem ipsum dolor </div>
            <div class="d-inline h3 float-lg-right"><a  href="/home/heritageprojects">orem ipsum dolor </a></div>
            <div class="row mb-5">
                <div class=" col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-8 px-0 px-xl-4 mx-auto">
                    <p class="text-justify">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dapibus feugiat leo. Donec tristique consequat odio vel imperdiet. Mauris efficitur a sapien et interdum. Morbi lacinia, justo quis pulvinar condimentum, nibh turpis vestibulum nulla, nec facilisis nisl ex et ipsum. Pellentesque maximus, ligula in dictum blandit, lectus est sodales nisi, ac tempor ante tellus eu turpis. Nam vulputate augue ut accumsan egestas. Donec efficitur, lectus ut aliquam viverra, nisl sem.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 slideshow">
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://placeimg.com/420/320/arch">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://placeimg.com/420/320/nature">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://placeimg.com/420/320/tech">.
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want us to help

Comment: i dont understan whats the problem

Answer (score -1):

Use the bootstrap class `img-fluid` in your `img` tag.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

Comment: maybe im an idiot but I cant see `img-responsive` anywhere on that page

Comment: I tried this and it is still cutting the images instead of making them smaller

Comment: @AonghasM You're right! They've renamed it in Bootstrap 4, I've edited the answer to reflect this. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @user6295447 have you tried using img-fluid instead of img-responsive?

Comment: @JamieMMX as i said in my question using fluid makes the images smaller than i would like. It does make them responsive but the images are too small

Comment: @user6295447 so the desired result is two equally aligned columns one with text and one with the image slideshow. And you want them to be responsive without the image getting smaller?

Comment: By smaller do you mean your losing a bit of the image or that the image is just getting too small to see

Comment: the desired result would be when the screen gets smaller so does the image. When it gets down to mobile size instead of having a smaller full image its a smaller image only showing 3/4 of the image. run the snippet in full screen then reduce the screen size and you will see what i mean